# How to add percentages on top of grouped bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, plot-annotations, grouped-bar-chart

Given the following count plot how do I place percentages on top of the bars?

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", hue="who", data=titanic)
```

[image]

For example for "First" I want total First men/total First, total First women/total First, and total First children/total First on top of their respective bars.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `seaborn.catplot` organizing function returns a FacetGrid, which gives you access to the fig, the ax, and its patches. If you add the labels when nothing else has been plotted you know which bar-patches came from which variables. From @LordZsolt's answer I picked up the `order` argument to `catplot`: I like making that explicit because now we aren't relying on the barplot function using the order we think of as default.

```
import seaborn as sns
from itertools import product

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

class_order = ['First','Second','Third'] 
hue_order = ['child', 'man', 'woman']
bar_order = product(class_order, hue_order)

catp = sns.catplot(data=titanic, kind='count', 
                   x='class', hue='who',
                   order = class_order, 
                   hue_order = hue_order )

# As long as we haven't plotted anything else into this axis,
# we know the rectangles in it are our barplot bars
# and we know the order, so we can match up graphic and calculations:

spots = zip(catp.ax.patches, bar_order)
for spot in spots:
    class_total = len(titanic[titanic['class']==spot[1][0]])
    class_who_total = len(titanic[(titanic['class']==spot[1][0]) & 
        (titanic['who']==spot[1][1])])
    height = spot[0].get_height() 
    catp.ax.text(spot[0].get_x(), height+3, '{:1.2f}'.format(class_who_total/class_total))

    #checking the patch order, not for final:
    #catp.ax.text(spot[0].get_x(), -3, spot[1][0][0]+spot[1][1][0])
```

produces

[image: barplot of three-by-three variable values, with subset calculations as text labels]

An alternate approach is to do the sub-summing explicitly, e.g. with the excellent `pandas`, and plot with `matplotlib`, and also do the styling yourself. (Though you can get quite a lot of styling from `sns` context even when using `matplotlib` plotting functions. Try it out -- )

Answer (score 14):

**with_hue** function will plot percentages on the bar graphs if you have the 'hue' parameter in your plots. It takes the actual graph, feature, Number_of_categories in feature, and hue_categories(number of categories in hue feature) as a parameter.

**without_hue** function will plot percentages on the bar graphs if you have a normal plot. It takes the actual graph and feature as a parameter.

```
def with_hue(ax, feature, Number_of_categories, hue_categories):
    a = [p.get_height() for p in ax.patches]
    patch = [p for p in ax.patches]
    for i in range(Number_of_categories):
        total = feature.value_counts().values[i]
        for j in range(hue_categories):
            percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * a[(j*Number_of_categories + i)]/total)
            x = patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_x() + patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_width() / 2 - 0.15
            y = patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_y() + patch[(j*Number_of_categories + i)].get_height() 
            ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), size = 12)

def without_hue(ax, feature):
    total = len(feature)
    for p in ax.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height()/total)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2 - 0.05
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), size = 12)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Answer is inspire from jrjc and cphlewis answer as above but more simple and understandable

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
total = float(len(train_df))
ax = sns.countplot(x="event", hue="event", data=train_df)
plt.title('Data provided for each event', fontsize=20)
for p in ax.patches:
    percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height()/total)
    x = p.get_x() + p.get_width()
    y = p.get_height()
    ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y),ha='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: count plot with percentage]

Answer (score 7):

- The easiest option beginning with `matplotlib 3.4.2` is to use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html).
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for more options and information about using `.bar_label`.
- The list comprehension for `labels` uses an assignment expression (`:=`), which requires `python >= 3.8`. This can be rewritten as a standard for loop.

  - `labels = [f'{v.get_height()/data.who.count()*100:0.1f}' for v in c]` works without an assignment expression.
  - Annotations for horizontal bars should use `v.get_width()`.
- The annotations in the example are percent of the total. For adding annotations based upon the total of a group, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851673/7758804).
- Also see [How to plot percentage with seaborn distplot / histplot / displot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68850867/7758804)
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Imports and Sample DataFrame

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# load the data
data = sns.load_dataset('titanic')[['survived', 'class', 'who']]

   survived  class    who
0         0  Third    man
1         1  First  woman
2         1  Third  woman
```

### Axes Level Plot

- Works with `seaborn.countplot` or `seaborn.barplot`

```py
# plot
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", hue="who", data=data)
ax.set(ylabel='Bar Count', title='Bar Count and Percent of Total')

# add annotations
for c in ax.containers:
    
    # custom label calculates percent and add an empty string so 0 value bars don't have a number
    labels = [f'{h/data.who.count()*100:0.1f}%' if (h := v.get_height()) > 0 else '' for v in c]
    
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='edge')

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Figure Level Plot

```py
fg = sns.catplot(data=data, kind='count', x='class', hue='who', col='survived')
fg.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
fg.fig.suptitle('Bar Count and Percent of Total')

for ax in fg.axes.ravel():
    
    # add annotations
    for c in ax.containers:

        # custom label calculates percent and add an empty string so 0 value bars don't have a number
        labels = [f'{h/data.who.count()*100:0.1f}%' if (h := v.get_height()) > 0 else '' for v in c]

        ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='edge')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With the help of [cphlewis's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168043/cphlewis) solution, I managed to put the correct percentages on top of the chart, so the classes sum up to one.

```
for index, category in enumerate(categorical):
    plt.subplot(plot_count, 1, index + 1)

    order = sorted(data[category].unique())
    ax = sns.countplot(category, data=data, hue="churn", order=order)
    ax.set_ylabel('')

    bars = ax.patches
    half = int(len(bars)/2)
    left_bars = bars[:half]
    right_bars = bars[half:]

    for left, right in zip(left_bars, right_bars):
        height_l = left.get_height()
        height_r = right.get_height()
        total = height_l + height_r

        ax.text(left.get_x() + left.get_width()/2., height_l + 40, '{0:.0%}'.format(height_l/total), ha="center")
        ax.text(right.get_x() + right.get_width()/2., height_r + 40, '{0:.0%}'.format(height_r/total), ha="center")
```

[image]

However, the solution assumes there are 2 options (man, woman) as opposed to 3 (man, woman, child).

Since `Axes.patches` are ordered in a weird way (first all the blue bars, then all the green bars, then all red bars), you would have to split them and zip them back together accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If there are more than 2 hue categories, I couldn't get these approaches to work.

I used the approach of @Lord Zsolt , augmented for any number of hue categories.

```
def barPerc(df,xVar,ax):
    '''
    barPerc(): Add percentage for hues to bar plots
    args:
        df: pandas dataframe
        xVar: (string) X variable 
        ax: Axes object (for Seaborn Countplot/Bar plot or
                         pandas bar plot)
    '''
    # 1. how many X categories
    ##   check for NaN and remove
    numX=len([x for x in df[xVar].unique() if x==x])

    # 2. The bars are created in hue order, organize them
    bars = ax.patches
    ## 2a. For each X variable
    for ind in range(numX):
        ## 2b. Get every hue bar
        ##     ex. 8 X categories, 4 hues =>
        ##    [0, 8, 16, 24] are hue bars for 1st X category
        hueBars=bars[ind:][::numX]
        ## 2c. Get the total height (for percentages)
        total = sum([x.get_height() for x in hueBars])

        # 3. Print the percentage on the bars
        for bar in hueBars:
            ax.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2.,
                    bar.get_height(),
                    f'{bar.get_height()/total:.0%}',
                    ha="center",va="bottom")
```

[image]

As you can see, this approach does what the original poster requested:

> I want total First men/total First, total First women/total First, and total First children/total First on top of their respective bars.

That is, the values added are the *Percentage of each Hue* (for each X category) - so that *for each X category* the percentages add to 100%

---

*(This also works with Seaborn's .barplot())*

[image]

---