# Issue in adding percentages to the top of bars in seaborn countplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, countplot

In a countplot I need to add percentages on top of the bars. I already tried the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749448/how-to-add-percentages-on-top-of-bars-in-seaborn) post. But I am getting the percentage only for the first bar and not for the remaining. Is there any way to get it solved? Code snippet as below:

```
import pandas as pd
my_data_set = pd.DataFrame({'ydata': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N'], 
               'p_f_test': ['False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'True']}) 

total = float(len(my_data_set))
ax = sns.countplot(x='p_f_test',hue='ydata',data=my_data_set)
for p in ax.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., height + 3, '{:1.2f}'.format(height/total), ha="center").astype(int)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you first remove the `.astype(int)` because you cannot convert a `matplotlib.text.Text` element to an integer.

Comment: If I remove then I get below error:                                                                  `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Comment: Interesting. One will need a [mcve] to see where that comes from.

Comment: okay it's simple dataset: 
 ydata p_f_test
0 N False
1 N True
2 N True
3 N True
4 N False
5 N False
6 Y False
7 N False
8 Y False
9 N False
10 N True

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is the dataset fine?

Comment: Sorry, I can't interprete the the text. Please [edit] your question instead. Also a *runnable* example would be beneficial, see e.g. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). A recent good question with such mcve would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55418807/4124317).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited the question with reproducible pandas code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bar in your plot that does not have an extent, i.e. `get_height` is `NaN`. You need to explicitely catch that case. Possibly you want to use `0` instead.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

my_data_set = pd.DataFrame({'ydata': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N'], 
               'p_f_test': ['False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'True']}) 

total = float(len(my_data_set))
ax = sns.countplot(x='p_f_test',hue='ydata',data=my_data_set)
for p in ax.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    if np.isnan(height):
        height=0
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., height, '{:1.2f}'.format(height/total), ha="center")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps. Is it possible to get the percentage grouped by p_f_test. That is total for False(N + Y) should add up to 1 and True(N + Y) should add up to 1.
That is bar for False 'N' should show 0.71 instead of 0.45 and False 'Y' should show 0.28 instead of 0.18.
Similarly True 'N' should show 1 instead of 0.36

Comment: Thats a different question. In general you may first calculate any numbers you need and then plot or annotate those numbers.