# How to plot percentage with seaborn distplot / histplot / displot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, displot, histplot

Is there a way to plot the percentage instead of the count on a distplot?

```
ax = sns.FacetGrid(telcom, hue='Churn', palette=["teal", "crimson"], size=5, aspect=1)
ax = ax.map(sns.distplot, "tenure",  hist=True, kde=False)
ax.fig.suptitle('Tenure distribution in customer churn', y=1, fontsize=16, fontweight='bold');
plt.legend();
```

[image: Image generated by the code]

Answer (score 16):

- As of [`seaborn 0.11.2`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-11-2-august-2021)

  - [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is replaced with the Figure level [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot) and Axes level [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot), which have a `stat` parameter. Use `stat='percent'`.
- For both types of plots, experiment with `common_bins`and `common_norm`.

  - For example, `common_norm=True` will show the percent as a part of the entire population, whereas `False` will show the percent relative to the group.
- The implementation shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851142/7758804) shows how to add annotations.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as ply

# data
data = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
```

### Figure Level

```py
p = sns.displot(data=data, x='age', stat='percent', hue='sex', height=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
p = sns.displot(data=data, x='age', stat='percent', col='sex', height=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

- Type annotations (`:=`) used in `labels` requires `python >= 3.8`. This can be implemented with a `for-loop`, without using `:=`.

```py
fg = sns.displot(data=data, x='age', stat='percent', col='sex', height=3.5, aspect=1.25)

for ax in fg.axes.ravel():
    
    # add annotations
    for c in ax.containers:

        # custom label calculates percent and add an empty string so 0 value bars don't have a number
        labels = [f'{w:0.1f}%' if (w := v.get_height()) > 0 else '' for v in c]

        ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='edge', fontsize=8, rotation=90, padding=2)
    
    ax.margins(y=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Axes Level

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
p = sns.histplot(data=data, x='age', stat='percent', hue='sex')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Percent by Group

- Use the `common_norm=` parameter
- See [seaborn histplot and displot output doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68865538/7758804)

```py
p = sns.displot(data=data, x='age', stat='percent', hue='sex', height=4, common_norm=False)
```

[image]

```py
p = sns.displot(data=data, x='age', stat='percent', col='sex', height=4, common_norm=False)
```

[image]

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
p = sns.histplot(data=data, x='age', stat='percent', hue='sex', common_norm=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! I ve been looking for how to do this for so long, thank you lots!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `norm_hist = True`.

From the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html):

> **norm_hist** : bool, optional
>
> If True, the histogram height shows a density rather than a count.
> This is implied if a KDE or fitted density is plotted.

Answer (score 0):

You could chose a barplot, and set an estimator defining the normalization in percentages:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.poisson(10, 1_000)))
ax = sns.barplot(x="x",
                 y="x",
                 data=df,
                 palette=["teal", "crimson"],
                 estimator=lambda x: len(x) / len(df) * 100
                 )
ax.set(xlabel="tenure")
ax.set(ylabel="Percent")

plt.show()
```

Giving:

[image]