# How to show the y-axis of seaborn displot as percentage

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, seaborn, histogram

I'm using seaborn.displot to display a distribution of scores for a group of participants.

Is it possible to have the y axis show an actual percentage (example below)?

This is required by the audience for the data.
Currently it is done in excel but It would be more useful in python.

```py
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

p = sns.displot(data=data, x='age', hue='sex', height=4, kind='kde')
```

[image]

### Desired Format

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @JohanC, the y axis for a KDE is a [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), not a proportion, so it does not make sense to convert it to a percentage.

You'd have two options. One would be to plot a KDE curve over a histogram with histogram counts expressed as percentages:

```
sns.displot(
    data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="sex",
    kind="hist", stat="percent", kde=True,
)
```

[image]

But your "desired plot" actually doesn't look like a density at all, it looks like a histogram plotted with a line instead of bars. You can get that with `element="poly"`:

```
sns.displot(
    data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="sex",
    kind="hist", stat="percent", element="poly", fill=False,
)
```

[image]

Comment: this has helped massively, thank you! On reading your answer, it became clear i was not asking the question correctly. i should have asked for a histogram but with lines instead of bars, with the percent on the y axis. thank you for your expertise!

Answer (score 4):

- [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) is a figure-level plot providing access to several approaches for visualizing the univariate or bivariate distribution of data ([histplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html), [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html), [ecdfplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.ecdfplot.html))
- See [How to plot percentage with seaborn distplot / histplot / displot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68850867/7758804)
- [seaborn histplot and displot output doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68865538/7758804) is relevant for the settings of the `common_bins` and `common_norm`.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

  - `data` is a pandas dataframe, and `seaborn` is an API for `matplotlib`.

### `kind='hist'`: [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html)

- Use `stat='percent'` → available from `seaborn 0.11.2`

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

data = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

p = sns.displot(data=data, x='age', stat='percent', hue='sex', height=4, kde=True, kind='hist')
```

[image]

## Don't do the following, as explained

### `kind='kde'`: [`seaborn.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)

- As per [mwaskom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576/mwaskom), the creator of `seaborn`: you can wrap a percent formatter around a density value (as shown in the following code), **but it's incorrect because the density is not a proportion** (you may end up with values > 100%).
- As per [JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc), you can't view the y-axis as a percentage, it is a [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). The density can go arbitrarily high or low, depending on the x-axis. **Formatting it as a percentage is a mistake.**
- **I will leave this as part of the answer as an explanation, otherwise it will just be posted by someone else.**
- Using [`matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter) to convert the axis values.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

data = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

p = sns.displot(data=data, x='age', hue='sex', height=3, kind='kde')

p.axes.flat[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
```

[image]