# Split \r\n, count, and plot with Python Seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have a csv file that reads the data from the "Toppings" column, however, cells with multiple values appear as one value with "**\r\n**" (e.g. **corn\r\ncucumber\r\npickles**). [Here is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pb0U.png), and [here is what the plot currently looks like (without any attempts at splitting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2agy.png).

How do I fix my code so that I split, count, and plot the total numbers of each topping request for supplies (separately)? I do not want to manually set split lines for each possible combination, because there are many more items and combinations that I have excluded for simplicity.

Here is my base code (without any attempts at splitting). Please be as specific as possible as I am still getting used to Python terms.

```
#These are a few libraries I have been working with.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns
import math
import io
import textwrap
%matplotlib inline
sns.set_style('ticks')
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

#access file
data = pd.read_csv('E:/testing_data.csv')
supplies = pd.DataFrame(data)

#plotting
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
total = float(len(supplies))
ax = sns.countplot(x='Toppings', 
                   hue="Toppings", 
                   data=supplies, dodge=False, order = supplies['Toppings'].value_counts().index);
plt.legend(loc='upper right', title='Supplies Needed')
plt.title('Distribution of Supplies');
plt.xlabel('Supplies', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Number of Occurrences', fontsize=15)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,10)
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '12'

for p in ax.patches:
    percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height()/total)
    x = p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2
    y = p.get_height() + .01
    ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), ha='center', color='black', size=10)

labels = [textwrap.fill(label.get_text(), 15) for label in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels);
```

Comment: 1. `supplies.Toppings = supplies.Toppings.str.split('\r\n')` 2. `supplies = supplies.explode('Toppings').reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851142/7758804) for current method of annotating bars using `.bar_label`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Trenton McKinney ^_^ I was stuck on that for a while.